# Depois de um certo tempo é impossível editar o comentário

Tags: suporte

Percebo que toda que vez que faço um comentário aqui no StackOverflow, depois de um certo tempo não é mais possível editar o comentário. Não sei se é um bug ou se é algo definido pela *comunidade administrativa da plataforma*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Abrir imagem em outra aba](http://prntscr.com/d4ba5x)

Esse é o meu comentário em uma questão. Como visto não tem a opção de **editar**. Isso é algo comum ou realmente é um "bug" ?

Comment: Depois de 5 minutos não é mais possível editar.

Comment: Isso pode ser debatido para que o tempo seja aumentado ? Na minha concepção 5 minutos é pouco tempo. Você pode querer melhorar o comentário ou editá-lo por alguma razão e não pode, dai temos que fazer outro comentário.

Comment: Há quem ache que é muito.

Comment: Comentários são infomações adicionais e temporárias, então não existem muitos recursos em cima deles, como por exemplo buscar algo nele. Em cinco minutos e 600 caracteres é possível dar o recado ;)

Comment: @rray só um complemento (até um pouco fora do assunto), mas apesar do sistema não ter como buscar oficialmente um comentário, eu deixei uma query pronta em uma [outra postagem do meta para esta finalidade](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2261/70). Em resumo, de fato não há recurso pronto, mas se alguém precisar de um paliativo para achar comentários de dias atrás, até existe.

Comment: O "Abrir imagem em outra aba" abriu a imagem na mesma aba para mim :/

Comment: Fui enganado por este "*Abrir imagem em outra aba*"

Comment: Também fui "trollado" só percebi que abria *in self* quando vocês falaram.

Answer (score 4):

Editar comentários que já possuem bastante tempo nem tem sentido, os comentários são mais uma *conversação*, se falhou em algo que gostaria de transmitir para as pessoas na conversa o certo é se manter na conversa comentando novamente.

Se foi um erro de digitação ou link quebrado que queria enviar o melhor apagar o comentário e postar um novo, pois o antigo com certeza com algum tempo todos já viram.

Entenda que comentários são **descartáveis**, não são respostas definitivas, são apenas para perguntar algo rápido, comentar algum erro que notou, comentar alguma falha na postagem.

5 minutos para editar é mais que o suficiente, depois de 5 minutos é provável que a maioria das pessoas ignorem o comentário mais antigo, então se tem algo errado nele apague-o e poste um novo seguindo uma linha cronológica mais correta.

**O único problema** dos comentários é a limitação de referenciar a apenas um usuário, ao meu ver deveriamos poder referenciar pelo menos 3 usuários em um comentário, algo como:

> *Guilherme disse:* O @bigown o AP está com dificuldade em X, talvez o @Bacco poderia transformar o comentário dele em uma resposta.

Mas isso já é outra história.

Comment: Na verdade o site tem comentário demais, quando passa de 3 ou 4 comentários é porque tem algo errado e se seles não podem ser apagados logo em seguida, é porque a postagem tem algum problema sério. Claro que cada caso é um caso, mas comentários são ruídos., idealmente não deveriam existir. Acho que o pessoal marca pouco comentários como obsoletos.

Comment: @bigown O Help não tem uma orientação clara do uso de certas flags, como por exemplo obsoleto, eu mesmo usei esta apenas umas ~5 vezes, e ainda usei com duvida. Tentei até pesquisar, mas mesmo para mim que sou acostumado com o o site e o Help isso me parece uma salada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=sinalizar+comentário